# Should/can a BizTalk BRE ruleset have multiple versions?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-rule-engine

Should/can a BizTalk BRE ruleset have multiple versions?

I've been given an export of some BRE rules and noticed that some of the rulesets have got multiple `<version>` elements, e.g.

```
<brl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/businessruleslanguage/2002">
  <ruleset name="ExampleRule">
    <version major="1" minor="3" date="2013-04-17T19:02:05.748159+01:00" />
    <version major="1" minor="0" date="2013-04-17T19:05:58.2361695+01:00" />
    <...

  <ruleset name="ExampleRule">
    <version major="1" minor="2" date="2013-03-29T08:23:43.6502257+00:00" />
    <...
```

Is this valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple deployed versions of a Policy are supported by the BRE itself and in the API you can specify a version number by overload, otherwise, the highest deployed version is used.

However, specifying a specific Policy version is not supported by the Call Rules Shape.  So, the Call Rules Shape will always use the highest deployed version of a Policy.

Whether or not you maintain multiple versions depends on the app in question.  I have seen cases where this is required for the business process or maybe regulatory needs.  A way to accomodate this in BizTalk is to use a "Master Policy" in the Orchestration which internally figures out and executes the appropriate Sub-Policy version.

As for the version elements, this appears to be a valid construct but I can't reproduce it.  The Wizard will only export one version or a Policy at a time, so, this was either exported in code using the API or was cut-and-paste together.  I have used the API and not noticed this.

Either way, the import function will apply the version info from the last version element in the xml, *not the highest version*, so if you reorder the version elements, you will get inconsistent results.

And one final wrinkle, the multiple version elements are preserved in the same order through import/export.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but my question relates to the <ruleset> having multiple <version>. The export I have contains the same <ruleset> twice, one has a single <version> (1.2), the other has two <version> (1.0 and 1.3). I'm trying to understand how this happens, i.e. if each change to the <ruleset> is recorded, why aren't there three separate <ruleset>, one each with 1.0, 1.2 and 1.3?   But in my example export, the 1.0/1.3 and 1.2 are different

Comment: Ah, I see.  I checked a couple of exported Policies and all have a single version element.  Answer updated...

Comment: Thanks yet again for the response ... yeah, I spotted that wrinkle where it's the last <version> element, not the highest that gets used ... nasty  :-(